# Error 404 en Django

Tags: python, visual-studio

**Vista/views.py** En la carpeta Vista es donde tengo el script views

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def saludo(request): #Primera vista

    return HttpResponse("Hola chavales, ya sale")

def dameFecha(request):

    fecha=datetime.datetime.now()   

    return HttpResponse(fecha)
```

**Proyecto1/url.py** En la carpeta de Proyecto1 es donde tengo todos los script

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Vista import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('', views.saludo, name='saludo'),
   path('', views.dameFecha, name='fecha'),
]
```

ingreso en el navegador localhost:8000/saludo

error 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error 404 esta relacionado con una respuesta por parte del servidor con el **status code** igual a 404, este tipo de respuestas por estándar específica que un recurso no ha sido encontrado. Tu idea es buena solo hace falta aclarar la diferencia entre la **ruta** y el atributo **name** vinculado a una ruta.

Para corregir el problema que tienes solo hace falta modificar el primer argumento de `path`.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Vista import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('saludo/', views.saludo, name='saludo'),
   path('fecha/', views.dameFecha, name='fecha'),
]
```

El primer argumento es el que especifica la ruta a través de la cual vas a exponer una vista o un recurso, el argumento `name` tiene un significado más sútil y es el poder específicar sobrenombres a tus rutas, esto da varias ventajas por ejemplo:

1. Es común que tengas enlaces que apunta a otras partes de tu página, sería tedioso tener que escribir toda la ruta completa cada vez que vamos a agregar un enlace, en su lugar podemos agregarle un sobrenombre y hacer referencia a ella a través de este que es más corto y fácil de recordar.
2. ¿Qué pasa si cambiamos un path simplemente por fines estéticos?. Tendríamos que ir a cada lugar donde hicimos referencia a ese path y actualizarlo. Teniendo el sobrenombre no tendrías ese problema, todos los enlances estarían hechos a través del sobrenombre y no de la path completa.

Una forma de obtener una path a través de su sobrenombre es con la función `resolve`, para mayor información visita la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)